# What does "事をかいて" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

From "銀の匙":

> 国では伯母さん夫婦の人のいいのにつけこんで困った者はもとより、困りもしない者までが困った困ったといって金を借りにくると自分たちの食べるものに**事をかいて**までも貸してやるので、...

So I can understand the first half of the sentence just fine, but the "事をかいて" part confuses me quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

事を欠く is actually a set phrase. Here is the entry for 事を欠く on [コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BA%8B%E3%82%92%E6%AC%A0%E3%81%8F-502883). The first definition in 日本国語大辞典 is:

> ① それがなくて不自由する。不足する。
> 1. To be inconvenienced by the lack of something. To not have enough of something.

So, this part of your sentence sentence means:

> 食べるものに事をかいてまでも貸してやるので 
> she lends them money even if it means we will struggle to feed ourselves.